# Android picture privacy filter (via Share intents)

Tags: android, images, image-processing, privacy, exif

Let's say I see a rare rhinoceros and take a smartphone picture to send it to Wikipedia via the Android Wikicommons app (which is accessible via "Share" on any picture).

If I do this directly, the picture will contain privacy-sensitive data:

- The date/time (as the filename)
- A lot of metadata as EXIF

What I am hoping for is something that would come in the middle and remove both of these (rename the file to a random filename and remove EXIF).

So, on a picture I would tap "Share>*Privacyze*", that would copy the file to a temporary place, remove both sensitive details, and then offer me the same "Share" menu from which I could pick "Share>Wikicommons" normally.

This "intents workflow" is required for speed reasons. Having to select the picture after details removal would be too time-wasting and error-prone (especially since the file would now have a random filename).

When I am in the action (taking picture) I have no time for anonymizing on-the-spot (this is better done later, when connected to Wi-Fi to upload them). So I should be able to anonymize pictures not only from any camera app, but also from any gallery software.

Comment: Do you think the Obscuracam is close enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 2):

For this and more you could use [Obscuracam](https://guardianproject.info/2011/06/23/announcing-obscuracam-v1-enhance-your-visual-privacy/), a great idea and app by the Guardian project.

It doesn't work in the way you describe, but can be used as a camera that takes pictures without leaving any sensitive metadata, thus adding no extra step to the process.

Note that as the application isn't designed for your use case, but I do believe it fits well.

[image: tmp.jpg]

Comment: Obscuracam is a camera by itself, right? I am still hoping for a separate app that would be compatible with any camera app.

Comment: Yes, it is. Can be used for pictures taken without using it, tho, but then you loose the "light workflow'' benefit.